# Not receiving telegram API events OR wrong python code?

Tags: python, listener, telethon

I am trying to listen to telegram chats/channels in Python.

My Python telethon code is login in OK but doesn't show nothing, "@client.on event" not been called.
I don't know if it is my code or anything else i have to configure or something in telegram.

Code below:

```
import configparser
import json
import re
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)
from telethon.tl.types import (
PeerChannel
)


api_id = #created ok not shown here 
api_hash = '' #created ok not shown here

# Here you define the target channel that you want to listen to: (tried ALL)
user_input_channel = 'grupovipdofortunetiger' #'https://t.me/grupovipdofortunetiger' #'https://t.me/+a9VjYVAYScllNTIx' # 'https://t.me/_CmgZDDJ_-E4Mjk5' #'https://t.me/tuition'
#https://t.me/+a9VjYVAYScllNTIx

#Initialise telegram client with API codes
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
#Start the process
client.start()
print('client started')

#Listen to messages from target channel
# OR Listen all events as you see uncommented 

#@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def newMessageListener(event):
    # Get Message text
    #newMessage = event.message.message

    # Apply 1st round of Regex for Subject for current messageContent - return list of keywords found (case insensitive)
    #print(newMessage)
    print('{}'.format(event))


with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```